# Linear time single-pair-shortest-path algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, asymptotic-complexity

Is there an algorithm that solves the *single-pair-shortest-path problem* in **linear time** for **mixed graphs** (i.e. directed and undirected edges or undirected edges represented as two directed edges), with **negative, real edge-weights** and **non-negative cycles**?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) only mentions algorithms for the *single-source* and *all-pairs* variant of the problem. I know that these solving one of these problems also solves the *single-pair* problem, but none of them works in linear time and with all the above criterias.

So is there a linear time algorthm for the single-pair shortest path problem with all the above criterias?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. Intuitively, no single-pair shortest-path algorithm which allows negative edge weights can be more asymptotically efficient than a single-source algorithm, since finding the shortest path to the goal may in the worst case involve finding shortest paths to each of some fixed proportion of the other nodes (in order to determine whether it's worth detouring to each one's negative-weight edges).

Comment: So if I've found a linear time algorithm for that it's actually new and it's not like there is no algorithm presented because the single-pair problem is not important enough?

Comment: Meh, I suppose so. I can pretty much guarantee you that you have not found such an algorithm.